# Can't get 2D transformation to work

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, lwjgl, linear-algebra

me and my budy is trying to create a 2D engine, but we can't get transformation to work, this is how it looks right now. We have created matrices for each element like scaling, translation etc. But we can't get the quad to move or do anything, have we done any math errors? This is what we get now, we just render the vbo and not using the shaders. With shaders I mean that we are GLSL.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JveBW.jpg

Transform

http://pastebin.com/dKRW244e

Matrix3f

http://pastebin.com/GY0872k6

Matrix4f

http://pastebin.com/f1YNuM09

VBO

http://pastebin.com/5zVgWYtK

BasicShader

http://pastebin.com/RyeSxibQ

Shader

http://pastebin.com/68tJTswq

VertexShader

http://pastebin.com/ffDvsL2Y

FragmentShader

http://pastebin.com/SWT5EKAi

From where we render and update

http://pastebin.com/dTG6HHDX

I think that I have messed up to bind the shaders to the vbo, is that right? And if so, how do I fix it...

Also, I just want answer in modern opengl, so no glBegin() and glEnd() Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious, as this may help, but in the class where you start, have you made sure to clear your screen before each frame? This is most commonly done using `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` inside of your main game loop.

Comment: I'm doing this before I call the render method. From a class called Engine.

Comment: Wherever that `glClear()` is, get it into your main game loop. The screen needs to be cleared once per frame in order to simulate any kind of movement, whether that be translations, transformations, or reflections.

Comment: I have, I even tested to put it right before the rendering of the vbo. Could you see if the transforming it done correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vertex shader, you wrote `gl_Position = in_Position * transform;`

This should return a matrix, rather than a vector. Given that your rectangle is plain white and you have made provisions for colour, I would hazard that your shader failed to compile at all.

`gl_Position =  transform * in_Position;` is the correct order for transforming a vector with a matrix.

Comment: I will test this after fixing the shader bug.

Comment: Can you see if my matrices is done correctly? And if I in transform should multiply every matrices to get the transform matrix?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with matrix * vector (this is actually the  convention the old fixed function pipeline did follow). GLSL will treat a vector as a row or column vector depending on the oder of the multiplications, so M * v is the same as v * transpose(M)